# Elasticseach error with null value for dense vector datatype

Tags: elasticsearch, vector, indexing

I created an index with a [`dense_vector`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dense-vector.html):

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/my_index?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "my_vector": {
        "type": "dense_vector",
        "dims": 3  
      }
    }
  }
}
'
```

When I index a document with a vector it works well:

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/my_index/_doc/1?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "my_vector" : [0.5, 10, 6]
}
'
```

BUT when I index a document with a null value for the vector it returns an error:

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/my_index/_doc/2?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "my_vector" : null
}
'
```

The error is:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "parsing_exception",
        "reason" : "Failed to parse object: expecting token of type [VALUE_NUMBER] but found [END_OBJECT]",
        "line" : 5,
        "col" : 1
      }
    ],
    "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason" : "failed to parse",
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "parsing_exception",
      "reason" : "Failed to parse object: expecting token of type [VALUE_NUMBER] but found [END_OBJECT]",
      "line" : 5,
      "col" : 1
    }
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

**How can I handle null value for vector type in ES?**

Comment: I am having the same problem. Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately no, the only solution is to remove the field which imply changing some things in my processing pipeline before indexing vector.

Comment: Too bad, I ended up filling the missing embeddings with a vector of 1's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of setting it to null you can remove that field from that particular document which is equivalent to setting it as null using the followingrequest

```
curl  --location --request POST 'http://{ip}:9200/my_index/_doc/{docId}/_update' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
     "script" : "ctx._source.remove(\"my_vector\")"
}'
```

Comment: I already tried, and yes, it works. But my records are automatically generated by a python process with a model where I can’t remove the « null » field. Obviously I would not have asked here if I could.

Comment: Even if the answer is not exactly what I was looking for it's the only solution so far.